# All but one stroke will scale in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, resize

I know the topic of scaling strokes in Illustrator has been answered to death and yes, I know how to do it. However, I have an outline image I did and when I resize this grouping of objects with the scale stroke and effects option checked, all but **one** of the lines scale properly. The singular line/object retains it's stroke and it's driving me insane. I also can't adjust the stroke of that specific line after I've resized.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the specific stroke has been "expanded" to a path and it's not a stroke anymore?
(A stroke will have a guide running through its middle, while an expanded line will have contour guides following the edges of the path.)
See example below, the top line is still a stroke while the bottom one has been expanded. They look the same, but you can't modify the thickness of the bottom one unless you play with the corner anchor points.

[image: Top line is still a stroke and the bottom one has been expanded.]

Answer (score 0):

Your path may have and "Appearance" assigned to it that will not scale. Verify if the object is coloured with an Appearance.